# An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the PutRolePolicy operation: The specified value for policyDocument is invalid

Tags: amazon-iam, aws-cli

I am about creating a aws cluster so I wanted to set Up an IAM Role for the Cluster. I have followed the tuto but once I typed this command

```sh
aws iam put-role-policy --role-name UdacityFlaskDeployCBKubectlRole --policy-name eks-describe --policy-document file:///tmp/iam-role-policy
```

I got this error -_-:

```
An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the PutRolePolicy operation: The specified value for policyDocument is invalid. It must contain only printable ASCII characters.
```

This is the command I used to create the policy

```sh
echo '{ "Version": "2012-10-17", "Statement": [ { "Effect": "Allow", "Action": [ "eks:Describe*", "ssm:GetParameters" ], "Resource": "*" } ] }' > /tmp/iam-role-policy
```

I still stack here any help!

Comment: Check you quotes. At times while editing, if you edit a file in windows and copy to linux, the quotes might be different and that can cause ASCII error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used another way to encounter the error.

#### Using Git bash Terminal

- Create a role policy document that also allows the actions "eks:Describe*" and "ssm:GetParameters". You can do this by setting an environment variable with the role policy:

> I have used the var instead of redirecting to a file that caused the issue for me.

```sh
EKS_DESCRIBE="{ \"Version\": \"2012-10-17\", \"Statement\": [ { \"Effect\": \"Allow\", \"Action\": [ \"eks:Describe*\", \"ssm:GetParameters\" ], \"Resource\": \"*\" } ] }"
```

- Check if `EKS_DESCRIBE` was really created by running this command `echo $EKS_DESCRIBE`

```sh
$ echo $EKS_DESCRIBE
{ "Version": "2012-10-17", "Statement": [ { "Effect": "Allow", "Action": [ "eks:Describe*", "ssm:GetParameters" ], "Resource": "*" } ] }
```

- Attach the policy to role

```sh
aws iam put-role-policy --role-name UdacityFlaskDeployCBKubectlRole --policy-name eks-describe --policy-document "$EKS_DESCRIBE"
```

> Another possible way using windows cmd is

#### Using Windows cmd

- Crate the policy using set cmd

```sh
set EKS_DESCRIBE="{ \"Version\": \"2012-10-17\", \"Statement\": [ { \"Effect\": \"Allow\", \"Action\": [ \"eks:Describe*\", \"ssm:GetParameters\" ], \"Resource\": \"*\" } ] }"
```

- check the var

```sh
echo %EKS_DESCRIBE%
```

- Attach the policy to the 'UdacityFlaskDeployCBKubectlRole'. You can do this using awscli:

```sh
aws iam put-role-policy --role-name UdacityFlaskDeployCBKubectlRole --policy-name eks-describe --policy-document %EKS_DESCRIBE%
```